# What action is required to reinstate this patent?

Tags: us6499671

In reference to the patent: [US 6499671 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6499671)

What action is required to reinstate this patent?

Answer (score 0):

This link describes **[How to Reinstate a Patent](http://www.uspto.gov/patents-maintaining-patent/maintain-your-patent#Reinstate%20an%20Expired%20Patent)**

I'm guessing it's more than 24 months lapsed, so see the second paragraph below.  My other guess is that you're trying to figure out how much you'd owe.  I didn't see how to determine that (aside from the fee schedule displayed, but then you need to know what is already paid).  Near the end of the page they list a phone number (also shown below).

**From the linked page:**

> If a maintenance fee has not been paid in a timely manner and the owner of the patent wants to get the patent rights reinstated, a petition and proper fees are required.

...

> If the date of expiration is more than 24 months, file a petition by submitting the completed form SB/66 and paying the proper fees; there are significant processing delays and the filing does not guarantee a granted petition. Contact the Office of Petitions at 571-272-3282 for assistance on filing a petition to accept unintentionally delayed payment of the maintenance fee.

...

> If you need additional assistance, please contact the Maintenance Fee Branch by telephone at 571-272-6500

Comment: I'm needing help with my software utility patent. Ta a really good idea and I'm willing to add someone else as a second inventor with me. I'm just really not trying to throw away $400.00